# Install application packed by snAppshot

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I have a folder containing an application I want to install on my home computer, however it has been packed by Novell's snAppshot utility. This means that the folder contains a bunch of .fil files, a .AOT file, a .ATX file, and a filedef.txt file.

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to actually use these files to install the application, preferably without installing the whole Novell suite on my home computer.

Answer (score 1):

The files that need to be installed get renamed to 0.fil and onwards, and I guess filedef.txt contains the list of file name mappings.

The problem is that I think the registry settings that are needed are not stored as file system objects, but rather are stored in eDirectory, that the Zenworks agent (either the standalone one, or the one that comes with Client32) reads out at install time.

I know it can pre-cache that info, so you can do the install offline, but I forget how the registry settings are stored in such a case.

The ATX file is pretty readable, it is a text version of the AOT definition file, (AOT is the binary format).

Alas, I am not aware of any great method to do what you want.